AT Commands for SARA-R510M8S (SARA-R5 evaluation kit)
I am using the SARA-R5 development board, specifically the SARA-R510M8S model (LTE + GNSS), with an Arduino Nano Every. My goal is to determine the GPS position and send its location via SMS, aiming for minimal power consumption.
To achieve this, I plan to use the power-saving modes of both the SARA-R5 and the Arduino Nano, along with some power-saving strategies. For instance, I want to activate the GNSS only every 10 minutes instead of keeping it on continuously. Additionally, I intend to use the LTE to send an SMS with the GPS position only if the device has moved a certain distance from the initial position—minor movements are irrelevant for my application. The Arduino Nano should also enter a power-saving mode when not in use.
The Arduino will be used to program the SARA-R5. I have looked at the AT commands for the module but am struggling to fully understand the datasheet (https://content.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/documents/SARA-R5-LEXI-R5_ATCommands_UBX-19047455.pdf).
Does anyone know some AT commands that could be useful for my case? I need commands to set the GPS to operate periodically and to configure the LTE module to send SMS only when the GPS detects significant movement from its initial position.
I have never worked with communication or GPS modules before, so I am a bit lost. Any suggestions you may have are welcome.

The module is a LTE-M / NB-IoT module, it requires the SIM card that support the service than a generic 4G sim card. You also need to check with your carrier to see whether they provision the SMS server over their LTE-M/NB-IoT network, in may network SMS only available on the generic 4G network, but not on the narrowband provision. If you are new to all this, don't try to write your own AT command parser, use a library such as TinyGSM.
